# assign javascript array value to dynamically created select option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want the options value from the array. I tried using the below script but it  is not appending the array value instead it is listing the value for the options as arr[++i]. But i want the value of array at that position.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 1;
var arr = ['1', 'abc', '3', 'def', '4', 'ghi'];
var row = '<tr> <td> <select name="roll_no' + counter + '" id="person' +     counter + '">';
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {    
row += '<option value="arr[i]">arr[++i]</option></td></tr>';

</script>
```

Comment: i don't think it's a complete code.

Comment: Please write complete code to ask question ur loop is getting close along with document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to escape both `arr[]` in your string correctly
2. in your example you close the `td` and `tr` in every loop, instead only at the end
3. you didn't closed the `select` element

```js
var counter = 1;
var arr = ['1', 'abc', '3', 'def', '4', 'ghi'];
var row = '<tr><td><select name="roll_no' + counter + '" id="person' +     counter + '">';
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {    
    row += '<option value="' + arr[i] + '">' + arr[++i] + '</option>';
}
row += '</select></td></tr>';

$("table").append(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```